# Nuget packages versioning in monorepo

Tags: .net, nuget, versioning, semantic-versioning, monorepo

I’m looking for some guidance about **how to do nuget package versioning in mono repo**. I have project that will have many infrastructure nuget packages that should be versioned independently. It is easy to have same version for all but when packages are not evolving in same time/speed it is the best to version them in complete separation. In contrast there will be many of such packages so creating separate repository for each one looks rather complex.

I’m thinking about separate branch for each solution that will be generating its nuget package but maybe there is better way?

Also I’m wondering how to deal with preview and final version flow – also use separate branch or maybe some tags?

Other thing is order of package build – when I have nuget dependency graph and would like to update leaf nuget is there any option to automatically update project using that nuget (maybe floating version but maybe there are some better options?)

There are many questions but I can’t find good resource with answers them in **mono repo scenarios**. Can someone point some good resource or maybe share with some experience how to do it right?

Comment: "There are many questions but I can’t find good resource...", and a good SO post, has just one question and usually involves code, config files, or other tangible examples you are having a specific problem with.  General guidance and best practices questions are best taken elsewhere.  I think you'll find that some time spent searching/browsing the internet, will turn up plenty of advice on the topic of mono-repo's.

Comment: All that said, yes, separate development branches per product is a common practice, but you must continually merge development branches back into master or another main trunk branch, or you lose all the benefits of a mono-repo.  It is a best practice to cut all public facing releases from release branches forked off of master, not from the product line development branches.  If you don't do that, you'll have product in the wild, that may not be compatible with the rest of your lines.  If that's okay, then why bother with the hassles of a mono-repo to begin with?